# How to organise shared partials in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm curious as to how people organise their shared partials in this specific case. In my application, an index of listings can be displayed at either /listings or /users/:id/listings urls.  Essentially either seeing all listings or my listings.

Both of the associated views /app/views/listings/index.html.haml and /app/views/users/listing/index.html.haml currently share a partial that does the bulk of the rendering.  Really everything but the title, heading, a back link, and some text if there are no listings.

Where would you locate this partial.  I'm torn between keeping it close to the main listing resource and also noting that it is shared a bit more widely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a partial that specifically lists `listings`, then I would vote for putting it in `app/views/listings/`. If it handles a more complex or nuanced collection of data, then it should go in a common folder (I've seen it called `shared/`, `common/`, or `widgets/`, but that's just a matter of preference).

I think the key is about whether it can be classified as something to handle the display of a specific object or if it's just some arbitrary block of view code that gets repeated throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your controller inherits from `ApplicationController`, and that your partial is named `_listing.html.erb`, then you could place the file at `app/views/application/_listing.html.erb`, and it would render with `render "listing"`.

To understand more about how this works, [see the RailsCast episode on template inheritance](http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance).

Placing commonly used partials in `app/views/shared` is also a valid approach, but you'd need to use the full path when rendering them, e.g. `render "shared/listing"`.